# Does setting the size of a margin set the distance between it and the element or between itself and the border/padding surrounding the element?

Tags: html, margin, padding, css

I have no idea why, but the box model is confusing me in CSS. More specifically, the difference between the margin and padding is confusing me. Whenever the size of a margin, border, and padding is set for an element in CSS like this for example:

```
div {
    margin: 20px;
    border: 2px;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Does this mean that the margin is 42px away from the element because the border is 2px and the padding is 20px away (20px + 2px + 20px) or is the margin the same distance away from the element as the padding?

Comment: margin is from the outside box and padding is from inside box and the border comes in the middle between those two
if you have a box with this css
means that the margin is 20px from the four directions 
followed by border 2px left is 2px right is 2px top is 2px and the bottom is also two
followed by 20px of padding in all directions